# How to send base64 decoded data through ajax to php file

Tags: php, ajax, base64, truncated

I want to send base64 decoded data to php file from ajax, but my half of the data get truncated, not able to send entire data through ajax to php file.

I am sending this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkAAAAJACAYAAABlmtk2AAAgAElEQ…/Hv5‌​9f3b//PQ+Q/3vcf35r/vmLQP0RPc/m74Zy4dP//wBHqel8UTBFDwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

and converting the base64 image to normal image like jpg

Any Help ?

Comment: Show your results, it will help to construct answer

Comment: i am sending this : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkAAAAJACAYAAABlmtk2AAAgAElEQ…/Hv59f3b//PQ+Q/3vcf35r/vmLQP0RPc/m74Zy4dP//wBHqel8UTBFDwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: and converting the base64 image to normal image like  jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Don't hurt me Stackoverflow gods. :-) Use JSON, not urlencoding. Make an object literal and then put your data inside. Send the data your PHP file and use json_decode.

```
var image {image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkAAAAJACAYAAABlmtk2AAAgAElEQ…/Hv5‌​9f3b//PQ+Q/3vcf35r/vmLQP0RPc/m74Zy4dP//wBHqel8UTBFDwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="};
```